# File Upload Issue in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API Swagger Integration with PowerShell backend

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm new to creating an API, I'm currently not to sure is my API can be execute in Swagger successfully. But the problem now is after I execute in Swagger, the file dialog window pops up as expected, but after selecting the desired `.CSV` file, the page keeps loading without any further response. Is there any i can solve the issue or it can show message either a successful setbaseline or fail to set baseline in Swagger?

This is my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.IO;

namespace myAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("setbaseline")]
        public IActionResult SetBaseline()
        {
            // Path to your PowerShell script
            string scriptPath = @"my own file path";

            // Start PowerShell process
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = scriptPath,
                    Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"{scriptPath}\"",
                    RedirectStandardInput = true, // Redirect standard input to send commands to the PowerShell process
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();

                // Automatically enter "F" to simulate user input
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("F");

                process.WaitForExit();

                // Read output and error streams
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                if (process.ExitCode == 0)
                {
                    // PowerShell script executed successfully
                    return Ok(output);
                }
                else
                {
                    // PowerShell script failed to execute
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, error);
                }
            }

            return Ok("Set baseline triggered successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is my Powershell backend script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function Set-BaselineFilePath {
    $inputFilePick = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $inputFilePick.Filter = "CSV (*.csv) | *.csv" #only restrict user to select .csv file
    $inputFilePick.ShowDialog()
    $global:baselineFilePath = $inputFilePick.FileName
    if (Test-Path -Path $global:baselineFilePath) {
        if ($global:baselineFilePath.Substring($global:baselineFilePath.Length - 4, 4) -eq ".csv") {
            return $global:baselineFilePath
        } else {
            Write-Host "Invalid file: The file must be a CSV file." -ForegroundColor Red
            exit 1
            return $null
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Invalid file path for baseline." -ForegroundColor Red
        return $null
    }
}

Function Show-Menu {
    do {
         Write-Host "    a) Set baseline file ; Current set baseline $($global:baselineFilePath)" -ForegroundColor Magenta

        $response = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', or 'H'"

        switch ($response.ToUpper()) {

            "F" { # Handle option F
                $global:baselineFilePath = Set-BaselineFilePath
                if ($global:baselineFilePath) {
                    Write-Host "Baseline file path set to: $global:baselineFilePath" -ForegroundColor Green
                    Write-Host "Baseline file path successfully set." -ForegroundColor Green
                    exit 0
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Baseline file path not set." -ForegroundColor Yellow
                }
            }
            
        }
    } while ($response -ne "C")
}

# Main script logic
Show-Menu
```

As this line is indicating the error below too after choosing the desired CSV file

```
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: StandardError has not been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to share with you that the approach you are using "execute a PowerShell script that launches a file dialog to manually select a file from a Windows Forms application" is not suitable for the web api service hosted on a server as it is non interactive. web service will not have access to the client's local files or UI.

Instead, you could design your API endpoint:

```
// POST api/apicontroller/setbaseline
[HttpPost("setbaseline")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetBaseline(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");
    }
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // code to process the memory stream pass the stream to a method that parses the CSV file
            bool isProcessed = ProcessCsvStream(memoryStream);
            if (isProcessed)
            {
                return Ok("Set baseline triggered successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Failed to process file.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}

private bool ProcessCsvStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    // CSV processing logic here
    // Return true on success or false on failure
    return true;
}
```

By using this method, you do not need to use the PowerShell script or any separate process. this Api endpoint will handle everything. after that you could use Swagger UI for the file upload:

1. Navigate to your Swagger UI (typically `http://localhost:<port>/swagger`).
2. Find and select the `setbaseline` endpoint.
3. Use the file picker to select a CSV file.
4. Click "Execute" to send the file to your endpoint.

If we talk about the error, you are getting "System.InvalidOperationException: StandardError has not been redirected." indicates that you attempted to read from the standard error stream without configuring the `ProcessStartInfo` to redirect the standard error.to resolve that you could add the code `RedirectStandardError = true;`